# What's the point of if(true)? c++

Tags: c++, boolean

I've seen `if(true)` used a bunch of times.

```
int a = 10;
if(true){
    int b = 20;
}
int c = 15;
```

I don't understand what the point of putting if(true) there. Does it always evaluate to true, meaning it always executes? It's not part of a function. It's just there. Does it have to do with memory allocation?

Comment: Maybe it's an attempt at creating a limited scope. Although just braces can be used for that.

Comment: In any half decent release compilation this will be optimized away. It might be there as a bad habit of leaving old code that used to have some real logic, but replaced with non-logic.

Comment: Scope limiter's a good possibility, but could also be a quick debug on/off hack. Without context who knows?

Comment: A clarification if you would be so kind: You say It's not part of a function. Can you feed us a bit more of what it is a part? Feel free to simplify and stub out any not-for-public-consumption class and namespace names.

Comment: Don't assume that all code makes sense. Sometimes people do stupid things, are lazy, have an off day etc.

Comment: Maybe earlier was a condition there, but it was commented out. In this case we can consider the "true" as a comment substitution :-)

Answer (score 3):

If one is fiddling with the code, it's very easy to turn

```
if (true) {
    // block of code
}
```

into

```
if (false) {
    // block of code
}
```

so this is a useful construct if you often need to turn a block of code on/off. It could also be a placeholder for future changes, where the boolean value is replaced with a (template) parameter or global constant or somesuch. (or a holdover from a former change that did the reverse)

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to :

```
{
    int b = 20;
}
```

maybe someone was using `if (false)` then switched to `if (true)`. `if(false)` makes actually sense because you are removing some code - it should not get into compiled exe, but it gets compiled by compiler - and checked for any errors.

Comment: Yes, an if(false) at the function start with labels in it that you can later jump to for recovery is a useful pattern.